# Emacs auto complete by sub-word prefixes

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

With IntelliJ, `thislo` can be auto-completed to `thisIsALongName` because it splits the symbol into words `this` `is` `a` `long` `name` such that `thislo` matches `this` and `long`.

Is there a way to config emacs to do the same thing with `auto-complete`?

Comment: This may be useful http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1wgauv/autocomplete_with_flexidolike_matching/